# Dropdown in Codeigniter modal does not populate and returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

PS. This question was already asked and the solution didn't work on me. Also I'm not very good in javaScript.

I want to populate dropdown using ajax and here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({           
            type: "GET",
            url: "popdropdown",                  //the script to call to get data          
            data:'',                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
            dataType: 'json',                //data format      
            success: function(data){    //on recieve of reply

                console.log(data);
                for(i in data) 
                    $("#pop_pcs").append("<div class='item' data-value=\""+data.i[1]+"\">"+data[i][1]+"</div>");

            } 

        });
    });
```

in the Controller

```
  public function popdropdown(){
        $this->load->model('asset_model');
        $data=$this->asset_model->get_all();
        echo json_encode($data);

    }
```

and in the Model

```
 public function get_all(){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('computer c'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        if($query->num_rows() != 0)
        {   
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}
```

this is the VIEW where it should populate

```
 <div class="field">
  <label>Installed In</label>
  <div class="ui selection dropdown">
    <input name="comp_id" type="hidden">
    <div class="default text">Computer Number</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div id="pop_pcs" class="menu">


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your view

Comment: @MayankVadiya okay included it already in the post. please kindly check im stuck in here :(

Comment: are you getting any error??

Comment: Hmm no its just displays undefined in the dropdown. But its okay now I just change the for(i in data) statement to $.each(data, function(index,item)